# jquery when custom wrapper functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-deferred

I have a custom wrapper function around jquery ajax.

```
custom.get = function (path, callback) {
  // do other things
  $.get(path, function () {
    callback()
  })
}
```

doing

```
$.when(custom.get(path), custom.get(path)).done(function (result1, result2) { callback})
```

doesn't seem to work. Is it supposed to work? Any alternatives for doing defers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the `jXHR` object (which abstracts a jQuery `Deferred`) from your `custom.get()` function in order to make this work:

```
custom.get = function (path, callback) {
  // do other things
  return $.get(path, function () {
     if( typeof callback === 'function') callback();
  })
}
```

You should also check if your second parameter passed in, really is a function to avoid unnecessary errors, see above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to return the ajax call, AND you should check to make sure that callback is defined before calling it.

```
custom.get = function (path, callback) {
  // do other things
  return $.get(path, function () {
    if(callback)
       callback()
  })
}
```

Comment: this will crash if any truthy value (beside a function) is passed in as second parameter.